# Не выполняется JavaScript на странице в WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Есть webview в Android, в него загружается страница, но без исполнения определенного скрипта. Как запустить script в загруженной странице из приложения, например при обработке нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял что речь идет об исполеннии javascript.
Для этого нужно разрешить исполнение javascript в WebView.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Если нужно делать это только по нажатию кнопки, то можно перезагрузить страницупосле нажатия на кнопку, предварительно разрешив исполнение javascript.